# Regular Expression to split string into nested array

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have this string: 1[2[5,6]],4,7[8,10]
It represents nested IDs to be used to build an array of navigation items.

I need to parse this string and create a multidimensional array of its values.  This will probably take several consecutive expressions and loops to build.

The end product would be an array like this:

```
1 =>
     2 =>
          5
          6
4
7 => 
     8
     10
```

I think all I need is an expression that will split the string on commas not inside of a set of brackets.  I would then loop over the substrings with the same pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this doesn't directly answer your question, but there's really no point in making your own parser.  Just store the data in a JSON string instead.

http://php.net/json-encode

http://php.net/json-decode

Comment: i considered json, but can you nest objects in json?